# API pagination with perPage and page when there is no offset support

Tags: javascript, rest, pagination

I have a requirement where I have to make an API request to fetch/load new items from client side for each button click.
Initial page load loads some items and new items fetched from clientside API call should offset those items. However the API doesn't support offset. How to achieve this using page and perPage.

For example: Say I have 8 existing items on the page. new items on click of button should load 10 items every time (items 9-18, 19-28, 29-38 etc).
How do i make this work using page and perPage, without making multiple calls for each button click?

I made it work with multiple API requests for each button click but I'm trying to see if there is an effective way to do that using single API call for each button click.

Comment: If i understand it correctly your initialpage quantity is different that the next pages?
In your example your initial page is 8 and all others are loading 10 items.
Is this intended? Or is it always the same number?

Comment: initial page items (8) are already loaded on the page. So i like to offset these when user clicks on button for getting new items. This can be easily achieved if API supports offset.